# How do I set loop such that a core in my PC do half while the other the other half in R

Tags: r, windows, parallel-processing, arima

I have `R` scrip that simulates `ARIMA` data and check the same data 100 times for `ARIMA order ARIMA(p, d, q)`. I have 2 core on the system CPU, how can I give an `R` command for a core to compute `1 to 50` while the second core to compute `51 to 100` simultaneously and then combine the result so that.

```
library(forecast)
system.time({
  for (i in 1:100) {
    a <- arima.sim(n = 50, model=list(ar = 0.8), sd = 1)
    b <- arimaorder(auto.arima(b, ic = "aicc"))
    #print(b)
  }
```

I am using windows 10 64 bits

Comment: You can use `parallel`, `future`, `callr`, and several other options for coordinating between different processes. There's also https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html.

Answer (score 1):

I use `foreach` and `doParallel` libraries to divide for loop into many parts.

I believe processing is better for the computer to decide how to divide the loops between the available cores.

```
#…
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

#detectCores()                   ### Count number of cores available
numCores  <- 2
registerDoParallel(numCores)

#for (i in 1:100) {          ### Original For loop
foreach(i = 1:100) %dopar% { ### Replacement parallel foreach loop
    #…
}
#…
```

Comment: `auto.arima()` function does not work with this `foreach` even when I load forecast package

Comment: I use `foreach(i = 1:100, .packages = c("forecast")) %dopar% { ` instead of `foreach(i = 1:100) %dopar% { ` in your answer and it worked